# Controller with HttpGet(...) gives error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am struggling to understand why I'm getting a Error 404 error when I use [HttpGet("/add-brand")] but without [HttpGet("/add-brand")] it works fine?

Here is my Controller:

```
public class BrandController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet("/add-brand")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddBrand()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

It works if the path is /brand/addbrand (without [HttpGet("/add-brand")]) but I would like to use [HttpGet("/add-brand")] instead.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is my Startup.cs Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

Comment: If you use `/route`, you remove the Controller's route. What you want to use is `[HttpGet("add-brand")]`.

Comment: I replaced [HttpGet("/add-brand")] with [HttpGet("add-brand")] and I still get Error 404

Comment: What's the route you're calling? And how are your routes configured in the startup?

Comment: I added my Startup.cs Configure method in the edit. The route is: https://localhost:5001/brand/add-brand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The route is: localhost:5001/brand/add-brand

So you expect the action to be callable within the `/brand` that’s coming from your BrandController. But that’s not how attribute routing works.

By default, ASP.NET Core uses conventional routing for controllers. The default template it uses is `/{controller}/{action}`. That is why accessing `/brand/addbrand` works if you don’t use attribute-based routing.

But as soon you specify the route via an attribute (either `[Route(…)]` or a method-specific attribute like `[HttpGet(…)]`) you are basically disabling the convention based routing. So that action’s route will *only* be determined by the route attributes. And since you only have the single `[HttpGet("/add-brand")]`, the actual route for your action will be `https://localhost:5001/add-brand` without an additional path segment for the controller.

You can put that back in if you like using `[HttpGet("/{controller}/add-brand")]`. An alternative would be to add a separate `[Route("{controller}")]` on the controller which will then cause all action routes to be concatenated to this. Note that this will disable conventional routing for *all* routes though, requiring you to specify it for every action.

Answer (score 0):

Camilo is correct, you don't need the leading / in the route string, the /brand/ is implied by the controller.

```
public class BrandController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet("add-brand")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddBrand()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced [HttpGet("/add-brand")] with [HttpGet("add-brand")] and I still get Error 404

Comment: So you are navigating to "https://hostname/Brand/add-brand/"?

Comment: pokes answer above explains it pretty well

Answer (score 0):

When you try /brand/addbrand (without [HttpGet("/add-brand")]):

MVC used routing template "{controller}/{action}
It matches brand with BrandController and addbrand with your action name

I'm curious why '/' is needed in [HttpGet("/add-brand")]. If you try [HttpGet("add-brand")] it should work fine.

Comment: I replaced [HttpGet("/add-brand")] with [HttpGet("add-brand")] and I still get Error 404